# How to merge two resultset into one resultset

Tags: sql-server

1st resultset

```
SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2) AS [MonthYear],
  SUM(ISNULL(CAST(TOTALFREIGHT AS float), 0)) AS FreightAmount
FROM OFFLINETRANS
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)
ORDER BY MAX(TRIPDATE)
```

2nd Resultset

```
SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE), 2) AS [MonthYear],
  SUM(TRIPCOST) AS FreightAmount
FROM TRANSVIEW
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE),
         DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE)
ORDER BY MAX(TRIPDATE)
```

How to merge two resultset into one resultset

Comment: UNION? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms180026.aspx

Comment: Agree, read up on the UNION and UNION ALL operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION operator like that:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' 
  + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2) AS [MonthYear],
  SUM(ISNULL(CAST(TOTALFREIGHT AS float), 0)) AS FreightAmount,
  'OFFLINETRANS ' AS FROMTABLE
FROM OFFLINETRANS
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)

UNION

SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE), 3) + ' ' 
  + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE), 2) AS [MonthYear],
  SUM(TRIPCOST) AS FreightAmount
  'TRANSVIEW' AS FROMTABLE
FROM TRANSVIEW
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE),DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE)
ORDER BY MAX(TRIPDATE)
```

You can also include the above query in a subselect and grup by monthyear to have both results grouped by month...

Comment: Freight Amount should be the sum of two result set for each month wise,not be repeated.

Comment: He's given you an answer to your question. It's your code to debug and ensure it's working, not ours. I'd advise looking into what's been done above and using that logic in your system.

Comment: Dinesh, al i have already said you have to wrap that query inside another one like that:
SELECT monthyear,SUM(FreightAmount) FROM ( The abouve union query without ORDER BY) GROUP BY MonthYear ORDER BY MonthYear

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, putting the second `SUM` in a sub query and add it to the original one.

```
SELECT
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 2) AS [MonthYear],
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(o.TOTALFREIGHT AS float), 0)) + 
(SELECT SUM(t.TRIPCOST)
 FROM TRANSVIEW t
 WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, t.TRIPDATE), DATENAME(YEAR, t.TRIPDATE) = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)
 GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, t.TRIPDATE), DATENAME(YEAR, t.TRIPDATE)) AS FreightAmount
FROM OFFLINETRANS o
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, o.TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)
ORDER BY MAX(o.TRIPDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If

> Freight Amount should be the sum of two result set for each month wise,not be repeated

Then use this:

```
SELECT  CAST([Month] as nvarchar(3))+' '+CAST([Year] as nvarchar(2)) as [MonthYear],
        SUM(DISTINCT FreightAmount) as FreightAmount
FROM (
    SELECT
      LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) AS [Month],
      RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2) AS [Year],
      SUM(ISNULL(CAST(TOTALFREIGHT AS float), 0)) AS FreightAmount
    FROM OFFLINETRANS
    GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3),
             RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE), 3) AS [Month],
      RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE), 2) AS [Year],
      SUM(TRIPCOST) AS FreightAmount
    FROM TRANSVIEW
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, TRIPDATE),
             DATENAME(YEAR, TRIPDATE)
) as t
GROUP BY [Year],[Month]
ORDER BY [Year],[Month]
```